# Combining PathPrefix and PathPrefix strip Traefik Docker

Tags: traefik

I am trying to create a frontend that matches all the routes to my backend but I am not succeeding. I have the following layout endpoints

```
/*
/api
/static-resources
```

I have succesfully mapped the /* resource to my UI. The /api and /static-resources endpoints should be redirect to my API backend. However for the /api urls (for example /api/users) the /api part should be removed (resulting in /users). This should not happen for the /static-resources. I now have used a workaround by defining two separate frontends but it would be nice to match this use case in one frontend. Currently this is my mapping:

```
traefik.api.frontend.rule=Host:$HOST;PathPrefixStrip:/api
traefik.static.frontend.rule=Host:$HOST;PathPrefix:/static-resources
```

But it would be great if I could do something like

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:$HOST;PathPrefix:/static-resources,PathPrefixStrip:/api
```

Is something like this possible or is this intended behavior to specify two separate frontends?

Comment: Did you find out answer for this?

Comment: No, I still use multiple routes